# If an invading army from an unknown land was defeated after inflicting major damage, what would happen to the surviving invaders?

Tags: society, warfare

A horde from parts unknown arrives on a continent, burns their ships, and starts taking over land. The Horde managed to conquer over half the continent and they burned down many major cities. They were defeated after a coalition of four armies trapped them in a valley pass and rained arrows down upon them causing the leader of the horde to die and the collapse the Horde's army.

After they are defeated what would happen to any remaining army members?

Edit: Both the horde and the society on the continent are early medieval ages tech. The Horde is similar to the Mongols Golden Horde except they are more heavily armoured.

Comment: This question is too broad, because we do not have enough material with which to determine which answers are most reasonable.  Consider adding more information to avoid having it closed.  Possible additions are: more information about the society that defeated the horde, more information about the society of the horde, how much damage did the horde do before it was finally beaten down?  What technology level are we targeting (For both horde and otherwise)?  Details like that narrow the scope so that we can provide better answers.

Comment: They burned their ships so I guess they will fight to the death because they are surrounded anyway.

Answer (score 9):

Burning the ships is an interesting detail.  It suggests a lot about the mindset of the invaders.  Historically, there are two reasons for burning your landing vessels.  The first is to preserve your country's monopoly on ship craft and navigation, to keep your intended conquests from returning to your homeland as conquerers.
The more interesting reason in your case involves motivating your troops.  Quite often, hordes are made up of conscripts, involuntary infantry drawn from the invader's prisons, work camps and feudal farms.  These types of warriors are not driven by patriotism or loyalty.  They are just looking for a chance to survive, and following the leadership of the invading force offers their best chance to survive.  Burning the ships, drives that message home. It says to every warrior, win or else; there is no going home again.
And it is the "or else" part which I think answers your question...

Slavery, forced labor or execution is what most failed invaders can look forward to.  The greater their success prior to loosing, the greater the resentment against them, and their subsequent punishment, will be at the hands of their new masters.  If an invader's horde truely scared its intended conquests, the remnants of that horde can look forward to hard labor, building defenses and weapons for their former enemies.

A few, the educated ones, the ones who bring valuable skills, might escape from this fate, but only after years of proving their value; first in the mines and construction sites, only later as skilled endentured servants.  If they are very lucky and work hard, maybe their children will be born free.  In a few generations, as the blood lines mix, as the fear and resentment fades, those children might even be considered equals in their new lands; at least by the enlightened among the natives.  For some, the stigma of their invader grandparents' crimes, can never be erased.